# "Sticky" interesting questions

Tags: feature-request

When I'm viewing the question lists, I sometimes find some interesting questions that I'd like to track. If I add it to Favorits, it's going to stuck there (for good probably), and it'll just pile up, making the 'favorites' list cluttered. The way I'm using `Favorites` is to mark some question that I might use in the future. So, not all interesting questions are 'favorites'.

What would be great is that I could `stick` some questions to be always displayed on top (*for me only*), and when the first bunch of replies passes or I loose interest, I'd untick it, moving on... I am aware of the "Interesting" tab list of questions, but that list is very dynamic, and moving the questions down as it gets populated, so it doesn't really provide me with a way to keep track...

The "stick" would be a per-user setting, ofcourse. It's usage would be extremely simple, easy to understand to users. In the future, the "Hot" questions could be more precicely displayed based on how much users 'sticky' some question, etc...

Comment: Which question tabs would they be stickied for? Would perhaps categorization or personal tagging of favorites be a better solution?

Comment: Once sticky, it thought it should appear on all tabs (exclusions may apply if others vote for it). Categorization of favorites is really pain to use, adds complexity, and really isn't in the spirit of the  "clean" site that stack is.

Answer (score 2):

Look for an addon for your favorite browser.  Custom ways to organizing bookmarks is well supported by them, you can get it exactly the way you want.  Beats trying to convince 400,000 users that your way is the best.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not trying to convince anyone - it's a suggestion that I think people may find useful... bookmarks is still a complicated way instead of a single click (imagine you'd vote for answers by bookmarking them - how many votes would we have?). Again, it's a suggestion - I know there are workarounds, I just think there shouldn't be any.